# Kobo H2O and symbol

Tags: kobo, display

I just got a mail from a person who told me that - while reading with a Kobo H2O an ebook I wrote - he could not see the character aleph in "ℵ<sub>0</sub>", and moreover the reader would not get past that page. (The ebook reads fine with the Firefox plugin, and with other ebook readers). 
I may understand that the Kobo does not contain the character ℵ, but I am puzzled that it blocks the flow.

Besides converting the character to a picture, does anybody have an idea about what to do in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Kobos have two reading engines: ADE/RMSDK for ePub2 books and NetFront ACCESS for ePub3 ([kepub](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kepub)) books.

In addition to checking your book with the [IDPF Online Validator](http://validator.idpf.org/), you might want to test your book with an older ADE version, e.g. [ADE 2.0.1](http://www.adobe.com/support/digitaleditions/downloads.html).
If it displays OK with ADE, the reader probably uses an older or incompatible reading app.

If it doesn't look OK with ADE, you'll need to embed a font with math symbols and/or convert your book to an ePub3 book and upload the (kepub) ePub3 version to the Kobo bookstore.

Comment: The ebook was checked with Sigil. I think I'll end up embedding a suitable font.

Comment: `The ebook was checked with Sigil.`
 
Note that the Sigil FlightCrew validator occasionally misses problems that epubcheck will flag. 

 `I think I'll end up embedding a suitable font.`
I'd recommend the [STIX fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/). (You can subset them with Calibre to keep the file size down.)